# Git Bash with Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, virtualbox, git-bash

I have downloaded [CentOS 7 minimal ISO image](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1503-01.iso) and created a `virtual machine` by `Oracle VM VirtualBox` on my `Windows 8.1` machine.

 I don't want use `VirtualBox` shell. I want use [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) as interface. The `Virtual Machine` must be running, but how can I use `Git Bash` as Interface to connect that `virtual machine`?

Is there any command like : `ssh username@localhost` to use in `Git Bash` in order to connect me to `Virtual Machine`? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same problem i have done several steps to achieve this,

1. Create Host Only adapter to take DHCP every time machine boots (from tools --> Network)
2. In your machine from VirtualBox go into network and attach that Host only adapter to machine.
3. Put your local machine's SSH key into the newly created OS from Virtualbox shell.
   (I have managed it with a aws webserver as i was not able to copy ssh key from local machine to VBox VM. Created nginx webserver and put my ssh key into the default html page and curl that machine's ip into VBox VM and redirect it to .ssh/authorized_keys )
4. Now configure /etc/ssh/sshd_conf to enable publickey authorization instead of password.
5. restart sshd service.
6. try ssh into virtualBox VM with local git shell with VBox user (eg. root or your user which you have created while installation.)
7. Boom! you are in!

Comment: If you are using NAT networking and don't want to switch to Host Only networking, you can use port forwarding to access the ssh server in your VM.  See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward